# What is the problem in my C code for pset3 CS50 Runoff? [solved]

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code below:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int candidate_rank = 0;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates

        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }

        if (candidate_rank < candidate_count)
        {
            candidate_rank++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        int preference = preferences[i][candidate_rank];
        if (!candidates[preference].eliminated)
        {
            candidates[preference].votes++;
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    int votes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        votes += candidates[i].votes;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > (float) votes / 2)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int votes[candidate_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        votes[i] = candidates[i].votes;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (votes[j] > votes[j + 1])
            {
                int x = votes[j];
                votes[j] = votes[j + 1];
                votes[j + 1] = x;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            return votes[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    int votes;
    bool tied;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            votes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            if (votes == candidates[i].votes)
            {
                tied = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tied = false;
                i = candidate_count;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!tied)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I ran check50 and this was the outcome:

```
:) runoff.c exists
:) runoff compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote correctly sets first preference for first voter
:) vote correctly sets third preference for second voter
:) vote correctly sets all preferences for voter
:) tabulate counts votes when all candidates remain in election
:) tabulate counts votes when one candidate is eliminated
:( tabulate counts votes when multiple candidates are eliminated
    tabulate function did not produce correct vote totals
:( tabulate handles multiple rounds of preferences
    tabulate function did not produce correct vote totals
:) print_winner prints name when someone has a majority
:) print_winner returns true when someone has a majority
:) print_winner returns false when nobody has a majority
:) print_winner returns false when leader has exactly 50% of vote
:) find_min returns minimum number of votes for candidate
:) find_min returns minimum when all candidates are tied
:( find_min ignores eliminated candidates
    find_min did not identify correct minimum
:) is_tie returns true when election is tied
:) is_tie returns false when election is not tied
:) is_tie returns false when only some of the candidates are tied
:) is_tie detects tie after some candidates have been eliminated
:) eliminate eliminates candidate in last place
:) eliminate eliminates multiple candidates in tie for last
:) eliminate eliminates candidates after some already eliminated
```

I tried fixing the errors but I was not able to do so. For some reason, when I tested my code, everything worked smoothly. I debugged the whole thing and tested if everything is working. I don't know if it was just luck that I didn't get any errors but I would appreciate the help in understanding where I went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? [In week 2 of CS50, you were taught how to use a debugger.](https://video.cs50.io/XmYnsO7iSI8?screen=5YGV1hcM_MY&start=2294&end=3777) Week 2 also has [two additional few short videos on debugging](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/2/).

Comment: `tabulate` doesn't clear the votes from earlier passes.

Comment: The find_min() function sorts the candidates by votes. But preferences[][] saves the voters' choices for each rank by each candidate's index in the array. After you tabulate the votes for rank 1, the candidates are sorted to be Charlie, Alice, Bob. So, after that, the votes supposed to belong to Alice are given to Charlie. Besides, your tabulate() function is wrong. You should let it count the votes for a specific rank when you call. In other words, define it as tabulate(int rank) and call it with tabulate(1), tabulate(2) and tabulate(3) for each iteration.

Comment: @CjY I fixed everything and implemented a rank system in tabulate(). I tried running the code again and the winner was Alice. Thank you for your help. I checked my code with check50 and received 3 errors from it. I hope you can look at my edited code and errors to help me find out where I went wrong.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I ran debug50 and went through all the code slowly. I fixed the code as shown by the edited code above, however, I came across 3 check50 errors. I tried fixing them but to no avail.

Comment: Now I found the original problem and got a better understanding of the runoff rules. Your original tabulate() was close. It just needs to pick all voters' first non-eliminated choice. The find_min() should just do what it says; no manipulation on any data. is_tie() can be simplified too. I will give a complete answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the problem is inside tabulate(). Based on the runoff rules, you need to count each voter's preference for the first non-eliminated candidate as their vote. You had this part mostly correct. The vote() function and eliminate() function are correct, too. However, the find_min() and is_tie() are over complicated and incorrect. For example, your is_tie() function first gets the votes of the last non-eliminated candidate, then you compare it to everyone else's. You can simply compare every candidate's votes to the "min" value passed in as a parameter. Here is a complete program. Hope this helps.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // find ith voter's first non-eliminated preference
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int preference = preferences[i][j];
            if (!candidates[preference].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[preference].votes++;
                // move on to the next voter
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    int votes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        votes += candidates[i].votes;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > (float) votes / 2)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int min = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            if(min == -1 || candidates[i].votes < min)
            {
                min = candidates[i].votes;
            }
        }
    }

    if(min == -1)
    {
        printf("Error, everyone was eliminated\n");
        min = 0;
    }

    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated && candidates[i].votes != min)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No downvote, you are new, but *Code-Only* answers are not helpful to other users. Code-Only answers do not explain what problems have been addressed, how you addressed each problem and why. Spend a few extra minutes and identify the problems your code addresses, why changes were necessary and why what you did is the right way to address the problems. Then your answer will be helpful to others.

Comment: Much better. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @CjY, thanks for your answer. Looking at the edited code that you wrote, it all makes even more sense now and everything is definitely more simplified. Thanks again!